# SQL Server query calculate diff. index per month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this :

```
Id    Machine        Year     Month       SumProductionPerMonth
==    =======        ====     ======      =============
1     Prod1          2016      1           1500
2     Prod1          2016      2           1800
3     Prod1          2016      3           1900
4     Prod2          2016      1           456
5     Prod2          2016      2           789
6     Prod2          2016      3           922
```

i get data like this

```
select table.Id, table.Machine, table.Year, 
table.Month, SUM(index) as SumProductionPerMonth...
```

I want to calculate the difference of the SumProductionPerMonth for each month x each Machine like this :

```
( SumProductionPerMonth Month N - SumProductionPerMonth Month N-1)
```

, and have a result like this :

```
Id    Machine        Year     Month       SumProductionPerMonth    Delta
==    =======        ====     ======      =============            ====
1     Prod1          2016      1           1500                     0
2     Prod1          2016      2           1800                     300
3     Prod1          2016      3           1900                     100
4     Prod2          2016      1           456                      0
5     Prod2          2016      2           789                      333
6     Prod2          2016      3           922                      133
```

how can i make a sql server query to get this results ?

Comment: What's your SQL Server release?

Comment: @artm : sorry, SQL server 2012

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh231256.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Simply use a "Windowed Aggregate Function", `LAG`:

```
COALESCE(SumProductionPerMonth 
          - LAG(SumProductionPerMonth) -- previous month's value
            OVER (PARTITION BY machine
            ORDER BY year, month), 0)
```

Edit:

Before SQL Server 2012 you can join using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS 
 (
   SELECT *
     ,ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY machine ORDER BY YEAR ,MONTH) AS rn
   FROM SourceT
 )
SELECT t1.*
  ,COALESCE(t1.SumProductionPerMonth - prev.SumProductionPerMonth, 0) 
FROM cte AS t1 LEFT JOIN cte AS prev
  ON prev.Machine = t1.Machine
 AND prev.rn = t1.rn -1
```

Comment: thanks but i make a mistake, my sql server version is 2008R2 ^^... so LAG function is not available ... :(

Comment: @Teetof:  I added a solution for SS2008

Answer (score 1):

*You can run this query on SQL server 2008 *

```
 WITH CTE
    AS (
        SELECT *
            ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY machine ORDER BY year
                    ,month
                )
            ,(
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY machine ORDER BY year
                        ,month
                    )
                ) / 2 rndiv2
            ,(
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY machine ORDER BY year
                        ,month
                    ) + 1
                ) / 2 rnplus1div2
        FROM SourceT
        )
    SELECT *
        ,ISNULL(SumProductionPerMonth - (
                CASE 
                    WHEN rn % 2 = 1
                        THEN MAX(CASE 
                                    WHEN rn % 2 = 0
                                        THEN SumProductionPerMonth
                                    END) OVER (
                                PARTITION BY machine
                                ,rndiv2
                                )
                    ELSE MAX(CASE 
                                WHEN rn % 2 = 1
                                    THEN SumProductionPerMonth
                                END) OVER (
                            PARTITION BY machine
                            ,rnplus1div2
                            )
                    END
                ), 0) AS balance_lag
    FROM CTE
    ORDER BY machine
        ,SumProductionPerMonth
```